# How to combine rows of a pandas dataframe as lists based on a condition that rows following a fullstop will be merged as a list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, list, dataframe

I have a dataframe which has two columns. I want to merge the rows as lists where the condition is that rows upto fullstop will be one list, rows after that fullstop will be another list. This should reflect on both the columns, however, the condition is based on the first column. For example:

| Tokens | label |
| --- | --- |
| Comparison | O |
| of | O |
| budesonide | I |
| Turbuhaler | I |
| with | O |
| budesonide | I |
| aqua | I |
| . | O |
| Rhinocort | O |
| Study | O |
| Group | O |
| . | O |

should yield the following:

| Tokens | label |
| --- | --- |
| ["Comparison","of","budesonide","Turbuhaler","with","budesonide","aqua","."] | ["O","O","I","I","O","I","I","O"] |
| ["Rhinocort","Study","Group","."] | ["O","O","O","O"] |

How do I approach the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```py
tmp = (df["Tokens"] == ".").astype(int).shift().cumsum().fillna(0)

x = df.groupby(tmp).agg(list).reset_index(drop=True)
print(x)
```

Prints:

```
                                                                Tokens                     label
0  [Comparison, of, budesonide, Turbuhaler, with, budesonide, aqua, .]  [O, O, I, I, O, I, I, O]
1                                         [Rhinocort, Study, Group, .]              [O, O, O, O]
```

Comment: Works like a charm. However, I needed the elements in double quotes. So I am adding these lines as well in case someone else finds the answer helpful. `x["label"] = [[f'"{j}"' for j in i] for i in x["label"]]
x["Tokens"] = [[f'"{j}"' for j in i] for i in x["Tokens"]]`